# Member access within misaligned address when trying to make a tree

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code to convert a vector into a tree but i am getting an error:

```
Line 51: Char 27: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'TreeNode', which requires 8 byte alignment (solution.cpp)
0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:56:27
```

```
TreeNode* deserialize(vector<string> v) {
        int i=0;
        TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(stoi(v[i]));
        queue<TreeNode*> q;
        q.push(root);
        v.erase(v.begin());
        while(v.size()>0)
        {
        if(v[0]==",")
        {
            q.front()->left=NULL;
            q.pop();
            v.erase(v.begin());
        }
        else
        {
         //  TreeNode* root2 = new TreeNode(stoi(v[0]));
           q.front()->left->val=stoi(v[0]);
            q.push( q.front()->left);
            q.pop();
            v.erase(v.begin());
        }
   
   return root;
}
```

Comment: `0xbebebebebebebebe` means the pointer was never initialized.

Comment: If you use a debugger, you will likely discover that, at some point, `q` becomes empty for whatever reason, so `q.front()` results in [demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). The shown code fails to check whether there's anything in the `q`, and takes it on faith before accessing `q.front`(). You should never assume anything in C++.

Comment: It would help to give the contents of `v` when you see this error. Or just use a debugger as already suggested.

Comment: Looks like the logic is wrong. The queue never grows beyond size one, whatever the contents of `v`. If there are two or more commas in `v` it will definitely crash (I mean, invoke undefined behaviour).

Comment: You never set `left` (or `right`) of anything to anything meaningful. There should be one `new TreeNode` for every node in the tree.

Comment: Further, it looks like your serialized format for a tree is something like `1,6,3,5,7,4`. This intuitively corresponds to multiple trees, so the format itself looks ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly happening with this code because you are not initializing left and right pointers of the node properly. They are set to NULL but it should not happen. They should be allocated memory using

```
new TreeNode()
```

where the values in the memory are initialized to NULL.

It should be like this

```
        TreeNode(){
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
        }
        TreeNode(int l,int r){
            e= r;
            s = l;
            left = new treenode();
            right = new treenode();
        }
```